# Python thread occasionally fails to return

Tags: python, multithreading

I am working on a multithreaded Python script that takes a list of file names and puts them on a queue. Most of the time it works however I'll occasionally find it stuck and 'ps -efL' will show two threads open for python script. I followed it with strace and 5 out of 6 threads returned but one just hangs out in futex wait forever.

Here's the block of code in question.

```
threads = 6 

for fileName in fileNames:
  queue.put(fileName)

for i in range(threads):
  t = threading.Thread(target=get_backup_list, args=(queue,dbCreds,arguments.verbose,arguments.vault))
  activeThreads.append(t)
  t.start()

for activeThread in activeThreads:
  activeThread.join()


def get_backup_list(queue,dbCreds,verbosity,vault):
  backupFiles = []

  while True:
    if queue.empty() == True:
      return 
    fileName = queue.get()
    try:
      fileInfo = lookup_file_by_path(fileName,dbCreds,vault)
      if not fileInfo:
        start = time.time()
        attributes = get_attributes(fileName,verbosity)
        end = time.time() - start
        if verbosity: print("finished in ") + str(end) + (" seconds")
        insert_file(attributes,dbCreds,vault)
        fileInfo = lookup_file_by_path(fileName,dbCreds,vault)

    except Exception, e:
      print("error on " + fileName + " " + str(e))

  return

def lookup_file_by_path(path,dbCreds,vault):
  attributes = {}
  conn = mdb.connect(dbCreds['server'] , dbCreds['user'], dbCreds['password'], dbCreds['database'], cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor);
  c = conn.cursor()
  c.execute('''SELECT * FROM {} where path = "%s" '''.format(vault) % ( path ) )
  data = c.fetchone()
  if data:
    for key in data.keys():
      attributes[key] = data[key]
  conn.close
  return attributes
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here that's causing a race condition? Or is there something else I'm missing.

Thanks,
Thomas C

Comment: Well, `conn.close` is missing a pair of parentheses, and calling `queue.empty` rather than just going straight to `get` (possibly with `block=False`) is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a race condition in your code:

```
while True:
     if queue.empty() == True:
        return 
     fileName = queue.get()
```

First the threads checks if the queue is empty. If it's not, it tries a blocking `get`. However, in the time between the call to `queue.empty()` and `queue.get`, another thread could have consumed the final item from the queue, meaning the `get` call will block forever. You should do this instead:

```
try:
    fileName = queue.get_nowait()
except Queue.Empty:
    return
```

If that doesn't solve it, you can just throw some `print` statements into the threaded method to identify exactly where it gets stuck, and go from there. However, there's no other concurrency issues jumping out at me.

**Edit:**

As an aside, what you're doing here could be more cleanly implemented as a `ThreadPool` or [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool):

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from functools import partial

def get_backup_list(dbCreds, verbosity, vault, fileName):
  backupFiles = []
  fileInfo = lookup_file_by_path(fileName,dbCreds,vault)
  ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = ThreadPool(6) # You could use a multiprocessing.Pool, too
    func = partial(get_backup_list, dbCreds, arguments.verbose, arguments.vault)
    pool.map(func, fileNames)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Depending on how much work each call to `get_backup_list` is doing, you may find it performs better as a `multiprocessing.Pool`, because it is able to get around the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), which prevents Python threads from executing across CPU cores concurrently. It looks like your code is probably I/O-bound, though, so `ThreadPool` might do just fine.

Comment: I bet that's what's happening, let me test it out a few times.

Comment: That was the fix, thanks! I looked at ThreadPool when I started this but I wasn't sure what was the best path to go down. I'll give it another shot.